# Admin template for flatpages

Tags: django, django-templates

I need to plug in reach text editor to admin page of flatpages. And I don't know, what the template are used to falatpages administration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Update*: 
One way is to use the [django-tinymce](http://code.google.com/p/django-tinymce/) app which supports the [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) rich text editor.  There's also an [example of using the widget](http://django-tinymce.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release-1.5/docs/.build/html/usage.html) with a flatpage form.

*Old*:
The default template should reside at "flatpages/default.html" but you can customize this through the admin interface.  See the [Flatpage templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/flatpages/#flatpage-templates) section in the django docs for more information.

Comment: No I'm asked not about template for view, but about template for admin panel. I need to customize it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to answer to my question. For admin panel of flatpage used default chenge_form.html. But if you customized it for your app, it wouldn't be work for flatpages without explicit destination.